# How to redirect the page to login page when the undefined error occurs using Angular2/typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, redirect

I have a page with side bar,as soon as i login it works fine.. But if i close tab and open again this error comes **"Cannot read property 'view_permission' of undefined"**, and the side bar will have no contents in it. If i change company or login again it works fine. Here i had written code to redirect to login page but when error occurs, it redirects to login page and within fraction of seconds it again redirects to main page.
I am here by sharing my code of ts please help,
ts code:

```
var page_permision = user.access;
  var url = this.router.url.split('/');
  var goBack = page_permision.filter(function(page) {
    if(page.viewName == url[1]) {
      return page;
    }
  })
  if((!goBack) || (!goBack[0].view_permission)) {
    this.router.navigate(['/routes']);  
  }
```

Please Help.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can add a check of `undefined` to avoid this error on same line, insted of checking it's length, if `page_permision` length is 0 loop will not run because of condition mentioned in loop `i < page_permision.length`.

```
 if(typeof page_permision != "undefined") {
        for(let i = 0; i < page_permision.length ; i++) {
          var name = page_permision[i].viewName;
          this.obj[name] = page_permision[i].view_permission;
        }
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. i will try.. I tried but it is happening in the same way.. Please help what can be done